# OO: Inheritance vs Service

Tags: php, oop, symfony

```
Class A
{
  public function __construct(Foo $foo, Bar $bar, MyCustomType1 $mct)
  {
   //...
  }
  //...
  public function getFooBarFunction()
  {
    $this->foo->aMethod();
    $this->bar->anotherMethod();
    //some other execution here
  }
}

Class B
{
  public function __construct(Foo $foo, Bar $bar, MyCustomType2 $mct)
  {
   //...
  }
  //...
  public function getFooBarFunction()
  {
    $this->foo->aMethod();
    $this->bar->anotherMethod();
    //some other execution here (same of Class A)
  }
}

Class C
{
  public function __construct(Foo $foo, Bar $bar, MyCustomType3 $mct)
  {
   //...
  }
  //...
  public function getFooBarFunction()
  {
    $this->foo->aMethod();
    $this->bar->anotherMethod();
    //some other execution here (same of Class B and Class A)
  }
}
```

As you can see this code doesn't respect the DRY principles. I can *easily* collapse `getFooBarFunction()` into *another* class and use that method.

---

A) Create a SuperClass and migrate `getFooBarFunction()` into it. I need to replicate `__construct()` also (`$this->` references).
**Pros**
 - quite easy to do
 - I can create an interface for `MyCustomType`(s) and use that into construct in substituion of concrete class(es)
**Cons**
 - what if child class need to add a parameter into construct phase?
 - what if I can't group `MyCustomType`(s) under same interface?

---

B) Create a SuperClass and use setters to "inject" `Foo` and `Bar` objects
**Pros**
 - quite easy too
 - I don't need to share constructor
**Cons**
 - what if I forgot to inject parameters? Have I to add additional explicit checks into SuperClass and raise exceptions?

---

C) Create a SuperClass and let `getFooBarFunction()` accept `Foo` and `Bar` objects
**Pros**
 - quite easy too
 - I don't need to share constructor
**Cons**
 - Is really necessary, in that case, inheritance?

---

D) Create an indipendent class (service?) and let `A`,`B`,`C` instantiate it and use it directly

---

What's best approach (or the "best practice") and why? There are any others?

## UPDATE

Class A, Class B and Class C are some objects that doesn't share any information each others (they represent a `Room`, a `Service`, a `Supplement`). Only common feature is that every class has a relationship with i18n table (each one with his own table). So my `getFooBarFunction()` is only a function used to retrieve static types (stored somewhere, it's not important) that indicates the type of i18n text (title, description, short name, and so on)

### UPDATE2 Real code

```
private function getTextTypeNameEntity()
{
    $text_type_repository = $this->getTextTypeRepository();
    $text_type_name_id = $this->container->getParameter('foo_project.text_type.name');
    $text_type_name = $text_type_repository->findOneById($text_type_name_id);

    return $text_type_name;
}
```

this function is `getFooBarFunction()`

Comment: If your PHP version is >=5.4.0 you can look onto traits. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: Software design is no different from graphic or industrial design. What you're asking here is basically "what is the best way to design a book cover (or a table)". Without knowing what this book is all about, and how this table is going to be used, the best answer I can come up with is "it depends".  Please describe your specific problem at hand.

Comment: @georg: this is exactly the specific problem. There's no obstraction apart method names.

Comment: @DonCallisto: you didn't give us the slightest clue about what your code _actually does_.  Back to the analogy, all we know is "I'd like to design a cover for a book. The book is about foo and it has bar pages".

Comment: @georg: if I gave that level of abastraction on my question is because I'm pretty sure that methodology (in this case) came first respect of objects (simple objects) involved. BTW I will update my question

Comment: @DonCallisto: thanks for that, but I still don't think your question can survive in the present form. What I would do is: 1) ask a new question, 2) post your real code, 3) don't poll people ("choose A,B or C"), instead, describe your problem ("too much repetitive code") and ask for suggestions. Also, since your code already works,  perhaps http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place.

Comment: @georg: I was not asking a poll to anyone. I just was providing some "solutions" to be evaluated. BTW Ok

Comment: @georg while what you say is mostly correct, I strongly assume that the question, if asked on codereview in this exact form, would quickly get closed as off-topic. The codereview [rules](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) clearly state that example code is not allowed :(

Comment: @Vogel612: sure, see `2)` above.

Comment: @georg: BTW I suppose that  D) is the best approach as this feature sems a "collateral" one (is spreaded into classes that teorically haven't nothing to do each other).

Answer (score 2):

**Answer for update 2**

You say this function only fetches text from an repository by an unique id. Without knowing the complete class this sounds like a code smell. A class should only do one thing and do it well. When you implement features, which are not strictly related, you extend the class over is boundaries. I would change the `getFooBarFunction` to only provide the text id:

```
public function getTextId() {
    return 'some-awesome-unique-text-id';
}
```

**Original post**

When looking at the code you provided I can only see one difference, the `MyCustomType`. I would type hint a shared interface which implements the signature for each method that can be called (interface basics). This can also be applied to the `Foo` and `Bar` classes. By using interfaces you can more easily swap actual class implementations.

You said: "What if I cannot group my custom type under the same interface?". This is tricky and one of the hard things to do with interfaces. Think of interfaces as a contract. If you change the method signatures of a class, but tries to use it in place of another you are guaranteed to run into errors. This will also make your code harder to maintain/read as you will attempt to handle edge cases all over the place. Try to stick with the interface.

You said: "what if I forgot to inject parameters?". First off this should be considered a bug/error and you as developer is responsible, sorry :D

You then later said, "what if I need to pass another parameter during construction?". To me that sounds like a different class all together and should be treated as such. Then if you need another parameter anyway, you can just extend this class and overwrite only the constructor. Something like the following.

```
abstract class AbstractImplementation {

    public function __construct(FooInterface $foo, BarInterface $bar, CustomInterface $custom) {

        // Initialize properties.

    }

    /*
     * This could also be declared abstract if each implementation
     * is different.
     */
    public function getFooBarFunction() {

        // Perform basic actions

    }

}

class ActualImplementation extends AbstractExample {

    public function getFooBarFunction() {

        // Perform specific actions

    }

}
```

Then if you need another parameter you can do. This should be considered an edge-case.

```
class ExtendedImplementation extends ActualImplementation {

    public function __construct(Extra $extra, FooInterface $foo, BarInterface $bar, CustomInterface $custom) {

        parent::__construct($foo, $bar, $custom);

        $this->extra = $extra;

    }

}
```

Hope my thoughts can help you, happy coding!

Comment: @DonCallisto - I cannot imagine any scenario where you would overload a method. There may be a reason why PHP (and many other languages) has not implemented such feature.

Comment: @DonCallisto - First of, there is no superclass, only an actual implementation that is being overwritten. I think you have `method overload` and `overwriting` mixed up. You can always overwrite a method/constructor unless the final keyword is defined. You cannot overload methods specifically, but the class as a whole using magic methods. In my example the constructor is overwritten, but the parent constructor is still used.

Comment: @DonCallisto - Read the documentation on [overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php). There you can see overloading can only be done with magic methods.

Comment: @DonCallisto It's overriding. The new constructor _overrides_ the old one, because it belongs to a child class.

Comment: @MikeSW: yes he was right, I was messing up the things

Answer (score 0):

I would opt for D + interfacing your classes. If `getFooBarFunction()` has nothing to do with the inner workings of A,B or C and the implementation is always the same in all classes then it shouldn't be a member of those classes. If the code calling A,B and C needs to know, that the method is there I would extract `getFooBarFunction()` in an interface and implement that in A,B and C. This way, the code outside can be sure the method is always there and is implemented in a working way.